# Why doen't the name of the file increment like the data of the file's array does?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

So the title I know is a little misleading with the contents, but my question is: with the code provided here, when I run `./tstats input1.txt input2.txt` the output is as follows

```
5 1 21 input1.txt
2 1 11 input1.txt
```

So it's obvious that the information from each file is going through but the names of the files aren't. Any idea as to why this is happening? Some small mistake I'm looking over?
Secondly, how would I tally all of the wcount results so that I have:
    7 2 32 total

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


enum state
{
    START,
    WORD,
    DELIM,
};

FILE*
input_from_args(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        return stdin;
    }
    else
    {
        return fopen(argv[1], "r");
    } 

}
char* get_filename_from_args(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;

    static char stdin_name[] = "-";
    if (argc == 1) 
    {
        return stdin_name;
    }
    else
    {

        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {   
            return argv[i];
        }
    return argv[i]; 
    }
}
void
wcount(FILE *src, FILE *dest, char* src_filename)
{
    int ch, wc, lc, cc;
    enum state cstate;

    wc = lc = cc = 0;
    cstate = START;
    while ((ch = fgetc(src)) != EOF){
        cc++;
        switch (cstate) {
            case START:
                if (isspace(ch)) {
                    cstate = DELIM;
                    if (ch == '\n') {
                        lc++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cstate = WORD;
                    wc++;
                }
                break;
            case DELIM:
                if (ch == '\n') {
                    lc++;
                }
                else if (!isspace(ch)) {
                    cstate = WORD;
                    wc++;
                }
                break;
            case WORD:
                if (isspace(ch)) {
                    cstate = DELIM;
                    if (ch == '\n') {
                        lc++;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    fprintf(dest, "%4d\t%4d\t%4d\t%10s\n", wc, lc, cc, src_filename);
}
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;  
    FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);
    FILE *dest = stdout;


    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if ((src = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[i]);   
        }

        wcount(src, dest, get_filename_from_args(argc, argv));
        fclose(src);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_filename_from_args` doesn't do what you think it does. Get rid of it entirely and just use `argv[i]` again at the call site.

Comment: I see you spotted the problem as fast as I did

Comment: Thanks, I figured those two functions were the same but I was given this code and told to manipulate it to do certain functions so I figured not to mess with that function, but now that I look at it, your right. It does exactly what input_from_args does! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You don't need `input_from_args` either.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
'wcount(src, dest, get_filename_from_args(argc, argv));'
```

is not stepping through the arguments contained in `argv`.

Suggest:

```
'wcount(src, dest, argv[i]);'
```

and eliminating the function:

```
'char* get_filename_from_args(int argc, char* argv[])'
```

Comment: ok, so with that being said; how would I tally up the numbers inside of the for statement in the main loop?

Answer (score 0):

regarding this sub question:

> Secondly, how would I tally all of the wcount results so that I have:
>   7 2 32 total

add three global int variables

Then when each value is available, add it to the appropriate global variables.
Then, in the end, printf the contents of those global variables

Comment: I've been told global variables are bad and that to stay away from them. This is only my second semester of prog so I'm quite new to C. First semester in C actually.

Comment: Global variables are sometimes the only solution. Try to use locals all the time with an occasional global